# Problems loading packages (ie. ggplot2) on R 3.2.2 caught segfault address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Tags: r, ggplot2, segmentation-fault

I just updated my R version to 3.2.2 on a Mac and transferred all packages to this version. Now upon trying to load certain packages (ie. ggplot2), I receive the following message:

> library(ggplot2)

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
 6: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 9: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
10: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
11: library(ggplot2)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

This also occurs when trying to load "devtools". If anyone is having the same issue and managed to find a solution it would would be great to hear from you.

Thanks!